# Google play services induces errors in my project

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-library

I am trying to add a Google+ sign in button in my app so that I can use the youtube API and provide an easy access to the user. However recently I updated my sdk and now on importing the google-play-services_lib in my workspace and further integrating the services in my project using the standard importing procedure (Project --> properties --> Android | add library) results in an red exclamation mark on my project and when I try to run it gives me a dialog which says there are errors in the project)

In Java build part I get an error which can be properly explained by the following screen shot:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? I am sure of the path.

Comment: simply remove the Google play service library from java build path and try adding library to project once again

Comment: Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace and then import it in the eclipse

Comment: Tried the same atleast four times since four days. Its not working!

Comment: Check that the Google Play like library is present in the same drive as the project

Answer (score 0):

Delete play services library from sdk (.../sdk/extras/google location )

Open SDK Manager and re-install play services library. Restart SDK Manager again to take effect.

Go to eclipse--> re-import play-services library from sdk (copy into workspace is optional).
Clean library project by project-->clean option

Go to your project, add this latest imported library to it.

Clean both library project and your project.

This should work..